# Playing videos in YT.player

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I display a list of links to youtube videos.

```
   document.getElementById('videos').innerHTML += "<div>"
                    + "<a href='#' onclick='showVideo(\"" + videoid + "\"); return false'>" + videotitle + "</a>" + videodescription + ""
                    + "</div>";
```

Click on any link and the video is played in its div.

```
function showVideo(arg) {
console.log(arg);

    var player;

                player = new YT.Player('response', {
                    videoId: arg,
                  //  height: '700',
                  //  width: '1000',
                    playerVars: {
                        controls: 1, // 1 is default value
                        autoplay: 1,
                        disablekb: 0, // 0 is the default value
                        enablejsapi: 1,
                        iv_load_policy: 3,
                        modestbranding: 1,
                        showinfo: 0,
                        rel: 0,
                        fs: 0 //Setting this parameter to 0 prevents the fullscreen button from displaying in the player.
                        //The default value is 1, which causes the fullscreen button to display.
                    }
              })
        //          player.destroy()

}
```

I click on a different link from the displayed list and I was expecting the existing video to be replaced with the new video but this doesn't happen, still first video is shown.
Isn't the variable player instantiated again? 
What would I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**`loadVideoById`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById):

> This function loads and plays the specified video.

Syntax:

```
player.loadVideoById(videoId:String,
                     startSeconds:Number,
                     suggestedQuality:String):Void
```

Implementing it like this:

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
        player.loadVideoById("Vw4KVoEVcr0", 0, "default");
    });
```

The variable **`player`** is your `new YT.Player()`, this code will load the new videoID = `Vw4KVoEVcr0` to the `YT.player`.

Reference:

- [jsfiddle sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/8bpQ8/1/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helped me to try something else. I used for _onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()_ same as in your code, but in my function _showVideo(arg)_ I put  _player.loadVideoById(arg, 0, "default");_ and the error I get is _Uncaught TypeError: player.loadVideoById is not a function_